# Using vim-go, gocode and godep doesn't work together

Tags: vim, go

I am using YCM, installing with this option `--gocode-completer`.

After having started Vim, I see the gocode daemon :

```
$ ps -ef | grep gocode
  501 53255     1   0  4:36PM ??         0:00.03 /Users/yamo/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/completers/go/../../../third_party/gocode/gocode -s -sock unix -addr localhost:37373
```

Completion works well on a built-ins (like fmt) but not on a dependency in GoDeps.

gocode displays the following message

> : Gocode returned empty JSON response

Nevertheless, godep seems have been correctly detected
`:GoPath` displays

```
/Users/yamo/Projects/.go/src/github.com/YannMoisan/openshift-skeleton/Godeps/_workspace:/Users/yamo/Projects/.go/vendor/:/Users/yamo/Projects/.go
```

Any idea to fix that ?